# How to flash MB1355C and/or MB1293C from the STM32WB55 Nucleo Pack on Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, stm32, nucleo

I would like to program the (MB1355C and/or MB1293C) devices from an [STM32WB55 Nucleo Pack](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/group1/13/58/22/1a/f2/ff/43/5c/DM00517423/files/DM00517423.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00517423.pdf) on my (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS) machine - preferably with the convenience of an eclipse based IDE that supports debugging features.

I installed

- STM32CubeProgrammer (version 2.2.1)
- Atolic TrueStudio (version 9.3.0)
- STM32CubeIDE (version 1.1.0)

and I now have the following `udev rules`

```
chandran@chandran-OptiPlex-9020:~$ ll /etc/udev/rules.d/
total 160
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec 13 14:11  ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Dec  4 13:44  ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   270 Oct 14 18:10  49-stlinkv1.rules
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   270 Oct 14 18:10  49-stlinkv1.rules.O
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   464 Oct 14 18:10  49-stlinkv2-1.rules
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   464 Oct 14 18:10  49-stlinkv2-1.rules.O
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   278 Oct 14 18:10  49-stlinkv2.rules
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   278 Oct 14 18:10  49-stlinkv2.rules.O
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   458 Dec 11 17:26  49-stlinkv3loader.rules
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   845 Oct 14 18:10  49-stlinkv3.rules
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   845 Oct 14 18:10  49-stlinkv3.rules.O
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   381 Dec  6 17:10 '#61-msp430uif.rules#'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   381 Dec  4 15:09  61-msp430uif.rules
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2145 Dec  4 15:09  70-mm-no-ti-emulators.rules*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58549 Dec  4 12:29  70-snap.core.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    79 Dec  5 12:11  77-msp430-blacklist.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Dec  5 12:10  77-msp430-blacklist.rules~
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 18450 Oct 14 17:33  99-jlink.rules
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 18450 Oct 14 17:33  99-jlink.rules.O
```

I am in the dialout group

```
chandran@chandran-OptiPlex-9020:~$ groups chandran
chandran : chandran adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

I downloaded an example project called `STM32100E-EVAL_USART_IrDA_Transmit` and it builds successfully, but I get the following error message when I connect the evaluation board(s) and click on `debug` to flash the micro controller

```
ST-Link enumeration failed
Error in initializing ST-Link device.
Reason: (2) ST-Link DLL error.
```

I get the same error message when I try the above with STM32CubeIDE.

I have tried shifting `JP1` as described in section 7.6 of the [users manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/group1/13/58/22/1a/f2/ff/43/5c/DM00517423/files/DM00517423.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00517423.pdf) but to no avail.

A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092674/error-in-initializing-st-link-device) on stack overflow deals with the same error message so I [got STM32CubeProgrammer to launch](https://askubuntu.com/q/1195872/444714) and tried making the changes suggested by @IsaBostan, but the development boards don't seem to be detected

[image]

How can I proceed to resolve this problem and program the boards?

Debugging ideas or suggestions are welcome, even if they haven't been tested...

Comment: Did you try to use openocd? Did you try to use the tool as the root user? Did you try other tools like `st-flash`? What are the permission of the appropriate device file that represents the stlink, search for `/dev/ttyUSB*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a question of permissions as suggested by KamilCuk

Launching `TrueStudio` as `root` and then clicking on `debug` solved the problem.

This is what worked on my machine:

```
sudo su
/opt/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_STM32_x86_64_9.3.0/ide/./TrueSTUDIO
```

STM32CubeIDE's debugger also works when launched as follows on my machine:

```
sudo su
/opt/st/stm32cubeide_1.1.0/./stm32cubeide
```

and STM32CubeProgrammer connects to the device straight away when launched as follows:

```
sudo su
/usr/local/STMicroelectronics/STM32Cube/STM32CubeProgrammer/bin/./STM32CubeProgrammer
```

My device shows up under `/dev/ttyACM0` with the following permissions:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root dialout 166, 0 Dec 28 11:56 ttyACM0
```

`openocd` and `st-flash` were not required.