# "No ST-LINK connected!" issue with Nucleo-F413ZH

Tags: macos, stm32, stm32f4, stm32cubeide, st-link

I'm trying to flash a basic LED blinking program to my Nucleo F413ZH board using the STM32CubeIDE, but whenever I try to debug it says:-

> "No ST-LINK connected! Please connect ST-LINK and restart the debug
> session."

The board has the PWR and COM LEDs blinking, meaning the USB I've connected to the board is providing power, I just can't upload any code.

I've tried using the ST-LINK upgrade firmware (https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link007.html) to install new drivers as that's what some people online have suggested but the program won't respond once I've downloaded it, which seems to be a side issue of not registering connectivity.

I'm not sure whether this is an issue with drivers or if my hardware is busted. I'm using macOS Big Sur.

Comment: Try and download cube programmer and check if you can see and connect to your chip, if not try some other cable. If you can see and connect to the chip double check your IDE debugger settings.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue with Nucleo-144 STM32H755. Are you able to solve the problem ?

Comment: I was able to solve the similar issue by just changing the cable. Thanks to @Sorenp for the suggestion. Using longer cable ST-LINK was not detected & when I used the smaller length cable it was detected

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 this problem occurs as a result of an incorrect driver priority as pointed out in this post.  [Error in initializing ST-Link Device - Failed to connect to device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092674/error-in-initializing-st-link-device-failed-to-connect-to-device/62821378#62821378) perhaps this solution might point you in the right direction.  I have set up several new M1 Mac Minis in the past few months for clients, Big Sur and the new M1 have several compatibility issues like slow network drive access and flashing screens, the Android M1 chip has dramatically less external connectivity which is why they went from 4 thunderbolt ports on the last intel Mac Mini to just 2. I would not be  surprised if Big Sur is the core of the problem.  Try a different computer if you have the opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error on ubuntu system while using stm cube ide, with st-link v2 programmer.
blue led was continuously blinking.
but solved the error just by reconnecting the usb-extention-hub, now when connected blue led is on (no blink), and now i can program and debug the target.